# Stripe Webhook: No webhook payload was provided

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am attempting to implement the Stripe API into my application and am hitting an error when receiving web hook data.  Now, when a successful charge is completed, the below code returns the following message:

```
    router.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {

    console.log("Received request");

    let data;
    let eventType;
    // Check if webhook signing is configured.
    const webhookSecret = stripeWebhookSigningKey;

    if (webhookSecret) {
        // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
        let event;
        let signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                req['rawBody'],
                signature,
                webhookSecret
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed: ` + err);
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        // Extract the object from the event.
        data = event.data;
        eventType = event.type;
    } else {
        // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
        // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
        data = req.body.data;
        eventType = req.body.type;
    }

    switch (eventType) {
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
            console.log(data);
            break;
        case 'invoice.paid':
            console.log(data);
            break;
        case 'invoice.payment_failed':
            console.log(data);    
            break;
        default:
            // Unhandled event type
            console.log(data);    
            break;
    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed: Error: No webhook payload was provided.

Apparently, others encountered this issue when the response was incorrectly formatted as JSON, which I remedied by including the following code at the top of the script, to no avail:

```
 router.use(
    express.json({
        verify: (req, res, buffer) => (req['rawBody'] = buffer),
    })
);
```

The Stripe CLI tool is clearly sending the requests but is logging HTTP 400 statuses.  What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Fixed, was due to an error in the server.js file routing to an external API file.  Can be remedied by conditionally activating bodyParser for external routers.